# Node child process can not run detached

Tags: node.js, process, fork, detach

I'm trying to fork a node child process with

```
child_process.fork("child.js")
```

and have it say alive after the parent exits. I've tried using the detached option like so:

```
child_process.fork("child.js", [], {detached:true});
```

Which works when using spawn, but when detached is true using fork it just fails silently, not even executing the child.js.

I've also tried

```
var p = child_process.fork("child.js")
p.disconnect(); 
p.unref();
```

But child still dies when the parent does.
Any help or insight would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

Node Version: v5.3.0
Platform: Windows 8.1
Code:

```
//Parent
var child_process = require("child_process");

var p;
try{
  console.log(1)
  p = child_process.fork("./child.js")
  console.log(2)
} catch(e){
  console.log(e)
}
p.on('error', console.log.bind(console))

p.disconnect();
p.unref();

//To keep process alive
setTimeout(() => {
  console.log(1);
}, 100000);
```

--

```
//Child
var fs = require("fs");

console.log(3);

fs.writeFileSync("test.txt", new Date().toString());

setTimeout(()=>{
  console.log(1);
}, 100000);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're executing your parent file from the command line, which is probably why it "appears" that the forked child is not executing.  In reality when the parent process exits, the terminal stops waiting and thus prints a new line, waiting for your next command.  This makes it seem like the child isn't executing, but trust me it is.  Also there is no "detached" option for child_process.fork

Add some console.log() statements to your child process and you should see input printing in your terminal even after the parent has exited.  If you don't it's because your child is prematurely exiting due to an error.  Run your child process directly to debug it, before calling it from the parent.

Check out this quick example:

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm using a process monitor and fileWriteSync'ing in the child though. It's definitely not executing.

The only different between seeing the child executing/not executing is the detached option being used on fork.

Comment: To clarify, it works fine when not trying to detach the forked child process. But when trying to detach it just doesn't work. So do you know of a way to create a detached child process using fork without using detach/ using detach in a way that works?

Comment: I believe child_process.fork detaches the child process by default, hence why there actually is no "detach" option for fork()

Comment: It seems you need to provide some more info to solve this issue.

You should edit your post to include which version of node you are using, and post your code if it is not too long.

To Try and troubleshoot this on your own, start simpler.  Start with the code I've provided in my screenshot and slowly add in the parts of your code.  Print log messages every step of the way to make sure things are executing as expected and so you can see where exactly things go wrong.

Comment: Cheers for the advice :). Like I was saying, the child executes fine if the detach option isn't passed to fork, so I guess it's just not meant to take it.

Problem is, that the child is definitely exiting along with the parent, when I kill it (either in the task manager or console) which shouldn't be the case if fork automatically detaches right?

Comment: Instead of killing through the terminal, use process.exit() in your parent code.  You should then see the behavior you expect.  I'm not sure how killing from the console or task manager on Windows works, but it seems like what it's doing is looking for all "Node" processes and killing them, in which case the child would be killed too.

Comment: If you are selecting individual PID's and killing them, its also possible that it's a bug/feature with how Windows manages forked processes.  Use Linux or Mac OS X (Unix), they're much more stable computing environments.

Comment: Interesting, it appears to be a node windows bug with forked processes. Using process.exit still produces the same behavior of closing both, but when run on a linux machine the child process sticks around like it apparently should.

Comment: Thats Windows for ya ;) the moral of the story is it's definitely worth investing in a personal Mac machine, especially if you're developing software that will run in the cloud (almost always linux), unless you're forced into Windows environments at work :(